# Partial derivative with respect to $ \left( \frac{dx^m}{ds} \right) $

Tags: partial-derivative, tensors

I don't understand how the following $$ 2g_{ml}  \frac{dx^l}{ds} $$ partial derivative was obtained below. It is supposedly the partial derivative of the value between the parenthesis.

$$L = \sqrt{g_{kn} \frac{dx^k}{ds} \frac{dx^n}{ds} }$$

$$ \frac{ \partial L} {\partial{ \left( \frac{dx^m}{ds} \right) }} = \frac12\left(g_{kn}\frac{dx^k}{ds} \frac{dx^n}{ds}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} 2g_{ml}  \frac{dx^l}{ds}  $$

Let me know if you need more infomoration.

Thanks.

Comment: do you understand the meaning of $\frac{ \partial L} {\partial{ \left( \frac{dx^m}{ds} \right) }}$?

Comment: I am not sure. I thought it was a partial derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let us abbreviate $\dot{x^k}$ for $\frac{d x^k}{ds}$.

Now we must manipulate $\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{x^k}}}$ as if $\dot{x^k}$ were a simple variable.

So, restricting to dimension two and instead of multi-indexing we use:
$$L=\sqrt{g_{11}(\dot{x^1})^2+2g_{12}\dot{x^1}\dot{x^2}+g_{22}(\dot{x^2})^2}.$$

Or better:

$$L^2=g_{11}(\dot{x^1})^2+2g_{12}\dot{x^1}\dot{x^2}+g_{22}(\dot{x^2})^2.$$

Then upon differentiating both sides: 
$$2L\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{x^1}}}=2g_{11}\dot{x^1}+2g_{12}\dot{x^2},$$
hence
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{x^1}}}=\frac{1}{L}\left( g_{11}\dot{x^1}+g_{12}\dot{x^2}\right).$$

Similarly
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial{\dot{x^2}}}=\frac{1}{L}\left( g_{21}\dot{x^1}+g_{22}\dot{x^2}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks @janmarqz,
It's more clear now. I assume the $l$ is just a dummy index, but I don't understand how the $m$ index got involved. You used $k$ though.

Comment: choosing $m$ to indicate which respect what variable you derive $L$ in $\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}^m}$ and $l$ in the summation $g_{m1}\frac{dx^1}{ds}+g_{m2}\frac{dx^2}{ds}+\cdots+g_{mn}\frac{dx^n}{ds}$, with $n$ the dimension over this geometrical objects are living.

Comment: I see. I thought the index of the variable to derive which respect had to be either $k$ or $n$.